# Why can i change value of int* in const int** type when getting memory from heap

Tags: c++, constants

have some issues with `const` qualifier.
I tried to do smth like this:

```
int a{ 3 };
int *p{ &a };
//const int **pp{ &p }; // FIXME: Compiler demands that p must have a const int *type
const int *const* pp{ &p }; // works here but it means, that I have a pointer to the const pointer to the const value
*pp = nullptr; // doesn't work cause of upper type
```

Results in error:

```
<source>:8:5: error: read-only variable is not assignable
*pp = nullptr; // doesn't work cause of upper type
~~~ ^
```

BUT: if i deal with `new` it works funny

```
const int **pp1{ new const int* {&p} }; // Here I have a poiner to pointer to const int, so I can change it
*pp1 = nullptr; // works
```

So, why does compiler demands a `const int* const*`? Compiler - MSVC, standart - c++17

UPD:

```
const int *p{ nullptr };
const int **pp{ &p }; // My intention
*pp = nullptr; // it works cause pointer non - const
```

But how can i get same result without const in `const int *p`?

Comment: const int** is pointer to const int*.

Comment: the two snippets do different things. Its not only `new` that you changed. Please include the error message in the question, it should already say why the first is wrong

Comment: If you use const `const int ** pp{ &p };` but if you use `const int *const*  pp{ &p };` or `const int *const* const pp{ &p };` it will work if you wanrt to `cout << **pp` but *pp = nullptr will not work cuz `pp` is const. If you want to understand const and pointers I recommend the following link:     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const

Comment: @rustyx, as i thought, const int** means that all pointers included in it also const (i.e. *(const int**) = const int*)

Comment: @taiwan12, thank you, i didn't find that question by myself

Comment: i added the compiler error message for you. Please update if you see a different one. Note that "works" or "works not" are not sufficient to describe a problem. It is always better to show the code/error message instead of rephrasing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are cases where this site https://cdecl.org/ for C syntax can also help with C++. For this:

```
const int *const* pp
```

it tells me:

> declare pp as pointer to const pointer to const int

For this:

```
const int **pp1
```

it tells me:

> declare pp1 as pointer to pointer to const int

Let's use that....

```
*pp = ... // ERROR !
```

When you dereference `pp` then you get a "const pointer to const int" (because `pp` is "pointer to const pointer to const int"). You cannot assign to a `const whatever`. What counts it the top level `const`!

```
*pp1 ... // OK !?!
```

When you dereference `pp1` you get a "pointer to const int" (because `pp1` is a "pointer to pointer to const int"). A pointer to `const int` is not constant. What counts is the top level `const`! It points to a `const int` but the pointer itself is not `const`.

Conclusion: The difference between your two versions is not the use of `new` but the type of the pointer that you dereference (and then try to assing to the pointee).

Comment: Thank you but last question. Why compiler force me to do my pointer const when I use const int* const* pp{ &p }? Second const means that a pointer will be const, not value, don't it?

Comment: @ShamilMukhetdinov `const int * const *` is a constant pointer `int * const *` is a non-constant pointer. The compiler does not force you, it just does exactly what you tell it

Comment: @ largest_prime_is_463035818, but why i cannot change pointer itself? Not the pointer value. I update question with some details now

Comment: @ShamilMukhetdinov if you update your question my answer will not be the right answer anymore. Please do not change the question after you received asnwers. You cannot assign to the pointer when the pointer is const. Sorry but I dont know how to better explain. If you are still a little confused thats fine, it is confusing

Comment: @ largest_prime_is_463035818, thank you, I understood a bit))